# is there is any prossible way to connect java with c++

Tags: java, c++, java-native-interface

i heard that JNI does that and is JNI platform oriented and can any one explain JNI for java and c++ with an simple example.

Comment: Please use www.google.com then come back with more specific questions.

Comment: At least, TRY to do some research on your own [I don't mean Stackoverflow], before you ask a question that requires much explanation.

Answer (score 1):

I did not try but I bet it will be within the first 10 hits if you google for it.
[JNIExample](http://java.sun.com/developer/onlineTraining/Programming/JDCBook/jniexamp.html)